# Fastest device to perform single-threaded SHA256 hashing

Tags: processor, encryption

I am in the process of designing a cryptographic Proof of Storage (PoS) that relies on **single threaded** computation of `SHA256` hashes. In practice, my algorithm is equivalent to computing for some string `S` the value `SHA256^N(S) = SHA256(SHA256(SHA256(...(SHA256(S))))`.

This forces anything computing that function to use only one thread, as each `SHA256` step needs the output of the previous as input.

Now, I know that ASIC miners exist that can compute `SHA256` hashes at an enormous rate. This, however, is due to their parallelism: completing Proofs of Work (i.e., finding zeros of hash functions) is an embarassingly parallel problem and can be computed very fast on massively parallel devices. This is **not** what I am looking for.

What I am looking for is the fastest device that would be able to compute my function, i.e., single-threaded computation of a `SHA256`, then the `SHA256` of its output, the `SHA256` of the result and so on.

I thought that maybe in this case the best hardware would be the fastest CPU in terms of single threaded performance: I found [here](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/singleThread.html) that `Intel Core i7-7700K` could be a good place to start looking for.

Is there any other known specialized hardware device that could carry out the task faster?

Comment: Have you done any research on your own into such devices?

Comment: Apart from a couple of days of Googling, I think I lack the hardware expertise I'd probably need to know where to look!

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: You can safely consider it unlimited. I am interested in the possibility of dealing attacks, so we can say that an attacker has unlimited resources at his disposal.

Comment: If your budget is truly unlimited, get someone to design and fab an ASIC for your specific task.  The cost will be in the millions of dollars, but that's not a problem on an unlimited budget.

Comment: Also note that you can also just take a Bitcoin miner ASIC and divide the hashing rate by N to see how many different such hashes they can do per second.

Comment: Relevant: [How fast can a SHA-256 implementation go?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/50618/23623) on Crypto.SE.